# If $X$ and $cX+Y$ are independent random variables, for $c\in\mathbb{R}$, what can we say about $Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real-valued random variables, with $\operatorname{Var}(X)>0$, and let $Z=cX+Y$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose we know that $X$ and $Z$ are independent random variables - I am interested in what this tells us about $Y$.

One possibility is that $Y=-cX+W$, where $X$ and $W$ are independent random variables. It seems to me that this should be the only solution - if $X$ is not purged from $Z$ then the two variables will share some information. However I am not sure how to (i) prove there are no other solutions, or (ii) if there are other solutions, how to characterize those solutions.

My working definition of independence is: $F_{X,Z}(x,z)=F_X(x)F_Z(z), \ \forall \ x,z\in\mathbb{R}$, where $F_{X,Z}$ is the joint CDF of $X$ and $Z$, and $F_X$ and $F_Z$ are the respective marginal CDFs.

Any hints/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: From $Z=cX+Y$, I think you can write $Y=-cX+Z$, where $X$ and $Z$ are independent

Comment: Thanks Nicolás. I agree. Is it possible to prove no other solution exists, or am I over-complicating things?

Comment: @NoCentes writing $Y = -cX + Z$ is just re-arranging $Z = cX + Y$. This is a proof that no other solution exists because your assumption about $Z$ tells you the form of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, @RhysSteele.